# C#, binding new BitmapImage, WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

Im new in WPF MVVM and i have a problem with binding a new `BitmapImage` to `Image.Source` control.

Binding image from filepath is pretty easy, but how bind new `Bitmap` or `BitmapImage` to `Image` label in WPF?

My scenerio:

**I have an method to do something with image (it is hide in `Model` folder in `Class` for methods for working on images:**

```
static public BitmapImage Init(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        //Do stuff

        return BitmapConversion.Bitmap2BitmapImage(newImage); 

        //BitmapConversion is my own class for converting images
    }
```

In this section, i made what i want to do with my Bitmap and return `BitmapImage`.

In **ViewModel**, i have this, opening an image and Init function that i want to:

```
namespace Test.ViewModels
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        public string filepath { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {

            OpenFileDialog openPicture = new OpenFileDialog();
            openPicture.Filter = "Image files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.tif|All files|*.*";
            openPicture.FilterIndex = 1;

            if (openPicture.ShowDialog() == true) 
            {
                filepath = openPicture.FileName;

                Model.Init(new Bitmap(filepath)); //init function from above
            }

        }

        public string DisplayedImage
        {
            get { return filepath; }
        }

    }
```

My **View** looks like:

```
<!-- row1 -->
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImage}" />

<!-- row2 -->
<Image Source ={Binding ?}" />
```

My question is, how to bind properly object like BitmapImage to source of Image label?

Thanks for any advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with ImageSource instead of string:

```
public ImageSource DisplayedImage
{
    get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri(filepath)); }
}
```

Or with your ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ...

        if (openPicture.ShowDialog() == true) 
        {
            DisplayedImage = Model.Init(new Bitmap(openPicture.FileName));
        }
    }

    public ImageSource DisplayedImage { get; private set; }
}
```

---

You should however consider to replace your `Model.Init` method with one that operates on a WPF BitmapSource instead of a WinForms Bitmap.

Comment: If it is so easy as you mentioned i feel dumb a little :D